# How enable amp-ima-video

Tags: video, video-streaming, amp-html

I've been trying to run the IMA video on AMP pages for days.

I have read documentation, followed step by step, and even use some basic template to use.

The problem is that the videos are not visible. look at the google chrome console and it tells me the following error.

```
error.js:170 Experiment amp-ima-video is disabled.
Wd @ error.js:170
(anonymous) @ error.js:108
f.assert @ log.js:325
log.js:319 Uncaught (in promise) Error: failed to build: amp-ima-video#1: Experiment amp-ima-video is disabled.
```

Well, for logical reasons it is clear that amp-ima-video is disabled. And for an even more logical answer I would have to enable it.

But how do I enable amp-ima-video?

I've searched in documentation, I've done several tests and nothing, I always get the same error.

I think it could be a browser error, but I take the surprise happens in all browsers and even on mobile phones

example code I used
https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-ima-video/

Note: (in the last page tells us that we must enable experiment. for this we must press a button to see the example video. something impractical if what we want is to use it in our own web page)

Hoping that the master minds will enlighten us with their wisdom and tell us either with a tutorial or a documentacion the most knowledgeable and clear to be able to enable and make use of the IMA SDK that is so useful.

Greetings and thanks for your welcome help.

Comment: Github (no instructions on how to enable)
https://github.com/ampproject

AMPproject (no instructions on how to enable)
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-ima-video

IMA SDK (no instructions on how to enable in AMP pages)
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/

Answer (score 0):

**Enable an experimental component**

For content served from https://cdn.ampproject.org, go to the AMP experiments page and enable (or disable) any experimental component by toggling them on (or off). Opting in will set a cookie on your browser that will enable the experiment on all AMP pages served through the Google AMP Cache.

For content served from any other domain, experiments can be toggled in the devtools console when development mode is enabled using:

AMP.toggleExperiment('experiment')
Any AMP file that includes experimental features will fail AMP validation. Remove these experimental components for production-ready AMP documents.

https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html

In addition, if you want to enable in your page use the following code and add it inside the header tag.

```
  <meta name="amp-experiments-opt-in" content="amp-ima-video">
```